# Setting a break-point causes asp.net to recompile in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, recompile

When i set a break point while debugging in ASP.net VS2012, the entire application restarts.

This was not the behaviour in VS2010.

Please how can i prevent the restart each time i set a breakpoint while debugging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the reason:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" explicit="true" strict="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

just set `optimizeCompilations="false"`